# Configuration of control parameters tol and delta in the rsolnp package

Tags: optimization, algorithm

I am working with the rugarch package which includes a solver.control argument. I am using the solnp solver. I can pass values for tol and delta. In the rsolnp the authors suggest that the control parameters need to be **specified accordingly to the user's problem**. However, I do not understand what tol and delta exactly do stand for (the description in the etiquette was unfortunately not clarifying this for me) and therefore it is quite obscure to me how I should choose the value of the control parameters. **Could someone explain what these parameters stand for?**

Comment: I assume you've looked at http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/Rsolnp/doc/manual.pdf which says: $\delta$ the perturbation parameter for numerical gradient calculation default $10^{-5}$; $\epsilon$ the relative tolerance on optimality and feasibility default $10^{-4}$? use the default values if you don't have a reason to change them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am quite certain that I need to change the parameters because my fitted coefficients of my model are off in comparison to similar models. Are there general rules on how to change these parameters?